# Targeting multiple DBMS using ORMs in the same application

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, orm, multiple-databases, targeting

My question is not if that possible but the level of configuration required to do that.

To be more clear, I want to connect to two databases that have the same schema but under two different DBMS (Oracle and SqlServer). I want to use in the same application an ORM to connect at run time to the selected (by user) database.

My question concern the configurations needed to perform this, will it be sufficient to change only the connection string passed to the ORM?

PS: please consider the configurations required by EntityFramework and NHibernate. If this is doable I want to compare the results to see which one is better.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use different dialects and drivers (NHibernate terminology).